# Monitor and limit internet bandwidth per network client

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, bandwidth

On a linux server with dhcpd that acts as the internet gateway for all clients of the LAN: how can I monitor the internet usage based on IP/MAC address, and deny internet access if a certain bandwidth consumption has been exceeded?

Comment: Which distro are you using? Some distros provide gui tools for this.

Comment: @Magus In my case it's debian 8. I use i3 and XFCE desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you could get this done with some scripting:

- Create firewall rules with `iptables` so that all bandwidth for each client passes through a separate rule. The firewall subsystem in the kernel will count network packets and bytes that a particular rule matched. You can see the counters if you run `iptables -vL`. You might want to use the `-n` option too, for performance: `iptables -vnL`
- Write a script that runs from cron and which checks how much data has been used by every client. Then if it's over a particular amount, have the script modify the firewall so that the client can not access the Internet anymore

Note that `iptables`' counters get reset when the firewall is cleared (i.e., after reboot, or when you do `iptables -F`. As such, you might want to have the script state its conclusions to some database or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is given here on Serverfault for limiting traffic

https://serverfault.com/questions/174010/limit-network-bandwith-for-an-ip

and for monitoring that traffic install iftop

Comment: I believe the question was about bandwidth consumption (i.e., number of bytes sent over a large period of time, like a month or so) rather than immediate bandwidth usage. In that case, it's not a duplicate

Comment: Yes, but I'm wary of using iptables to do this. Your method will produce network errors on the user's end.

Comment: The top answer gives a way to do this without stopping the connection. Not a duplicate, but it answers the question.

Comment: I believe that's what the OP wants, but hey

Comment: Ok. I agree with you. I'm voting your answer up.

Comment: He did literally ask for them to be booted off in that case. I don't think it's a good idea but yes that's what he wants.

Comment: I agree with that, but I'm only answering questions :-)